# How to save an invalid XHTML website as valid XML

Tags: html, xml, macos, dom, xhtml

There is a website which is *invalid* XHTML (some closing tags are missing).

I want to process its contents with XSLT, but therefore, I need a valid XML input.

Is it possible to save the DOM document the browser creates from the invalid XHTML input as valid XML/XHTML?

Comment: Actually it isn't XHTML. If document isn't well-formed and it's still displayed in browser, you're sending the `text/html` MIME type => it's HTML, no matter what doctype you use and you can't use XSLT directly in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. There are several libraries that can handle invalid markup and return it as valid xml/xhtml.
One of them is tidy http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

If you have access to the website, you could print the output into a buffer and then clean it ...
BTW: valid xhtml is also valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

If you using .NET as a server side technology, you can try [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
It can load invalid HTML/XHTML and convert it to valid XML.